# How do I search for a substring within a string and return that string

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add the following logic to the below Custom Javascript variable within GTM:
"Find if a string contains this word, and return that word"

```
function() {
  var el = {{Click Element}};
  el = el.parentElement;
  var classes = el.className;

  return classes ;
}
```

In the above code the classes variable returns the following string:

```
'wp-block-button jungle-cta tiger-animal'
```

I'm trying to do the following: if the string contains "tiger" then return "tiger-animal" and only that.

I am applying this function on different CTAs on the same landing page. Each CTA has a tiger constant as part of the class name. So one CTA is "tiger-animal", the other "tiger-something", "tiger-word" etc. I'm looking for logic that is agnostic of what follows after "tiger-". If the tiger is found then parse that word which contains the tiger and return it.

**Update:**

The below works now! Thank you.

```
function() {
  var el = {{Click Element}};
  el = el.parentElement;
  var classes = el.className;
  var regex = /tiger-[a-z]*/g;
  var found = classes.match(regex);
  return found[0]
}
```

Comment: can you please include an example of the unsuccessful code you've tried?

Comment: I don't know why every GTM user here on stackoverflow is so dead set against using GTMs built in features. Use a regex table and feed it with the class variable, that will allow you to maintain a regex for each use case and you won't have to do custom coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the code here to match what you mentioned in the comment. It now returns the string if matches, otherwise returns undefined:

```
function checkIfTiger(input) {
  const regex = /tiger-[a-z]*/g;
  const found = input.match(regex)
  return found !== null && found[0]
}

checkIfTiger("fsd adfj adkfj tiger-adsf dfadf")
// returns "tiger-asdf"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

How about using the .includes property. For example:

```
let a = 'wp-block-button jungle-cta tiger-animal'

function checkIfTiger() {
  if(a.includes("tiger")) {
    return "tiger-animal"
  }
}

checkIfTiger()
```

Actually, here is a version with lesser code. It return "tiger-animal" if "tiger" is present in whatever you're checking, otherwise returns false:

```
let a = 'wp-block-button jungle-cta tiger-animal'

function checkIfTiger() {
  return a.includes("tiger") && "tiger-animal"
}

checkIfTiger()
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. What I forgot to mention is that I am applying this function on different CTAs on the same landing page. Each CTA has tiger constant as part of the class name. So one CTA is "tiger-animal", "tiger-something", "tiger-word" etc. 
I'm looking for logic that is agnostic of what follows after "tiger-". 
If tiger is found then parse that word which contains tiger and return it.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried your logic with my existing code but GTM returns undefined. Updated the description.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for letting me know. I am not sure about GTM. I guess you mean Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 1):

If the only important change you're looking to make to this function is that it will return the string `"tiger-animal"` if your variable `classes` contains the substring `"tiger"`, then I recommend a simple [if/else statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) that makes use of the [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method, which returns `true` if your string contains a specified substring, or `false` if it doesn't. For example:

```
function() {
  var el = {{Click Element}};
  el = el.parentElement;
  var classes = el.className;
  
  if (classes.includes("tiger")) {
    return "tiger-animal";
  } else {
    return classes;
  }
}
```

And if you don't feel like it'll hurt readability, the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) uses fewer lines:

```
function() {
  var el = {{Click Element}};
  el = el.parentElement;
  var classes = el.className;
      
  return (classes.includes("tiger") ? "tiger-animal" : classes)
}
```

Both of these functions will either return `classes`, or, if `classes` contains the substring `"tiger"` it will return the string `"tiger-animal"`.

**For any casual passersby wanting to know how to check for substrings**, here's a more barebones function demonstrating this principle using less of the question's original context:

```
function tigerChecker(string) {
      let classes = string
      
      if (classes.includes("tiger")) {
        return "tiger-animal";
      } else {
        return classes;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. What I forgot to mention is that I am applying this function on different CTAs on the same landing page. Each CTA has tiger constant as part of the class name. So one CTA is "tiger-animal", "tiger-something", "tiger-word" etc. 
I'm looking for logic that is agnostic of what follows after "tiger-". 
If tiger is found then parse that word which contains tiger and return it.